# Cannot detect Linux distribution or it’s unsupported

Tags: linux, docker, docker-cloud

Getting this error when run this command which was given by the web dashboard(changed the key to *)

```
sudo curl -Ls https://get.cloud.docker.com/ | sudo -H sh -s f74*************************
ERROR: Cannot detect Linux distribution or it's unsupported
Learn more: https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/tutorials/byoh/
```

while the docker info command gives the following output:

```
sudo docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 0
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-37-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.56 GiB
Name: G1
ID: WNIV:V2NZ:**********
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Is docker cloud not supported on Ubuntu 14.04.1? Any tips on how to resolve this?

Comment: ubuntu 14.01 seems supported, if you read that shell script it tries to detect `ubuntu` but not any specific version. check `get_distribution_type` in that shell file and try to do it yourself to see what doesnt match

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Very minimal bash scripting experience.